# Power pivot running total issue

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax, cumulative-sum

Not sure if anyone can help me with a DAX issue I'm having. I've followed the advice on this blog (http://javierguillen.wordpress.com/2012/11/28/running-total-techniques-in-dax/). My measures are in the same format as this:

```
CALCULATE(     SUM( FactSales[SalesAmount] ),
    FILTER(
        ALL( DimDate) ,
        DimDate[Datekey] <= MAX( DimDate[Datekey] )
    )
)
```

I have two measures: a running target and running actuals. I want the actuals line to stop at the current date rather than flat lining from current date to the end of the year.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Tom

Comment: Tom, can you please post some sample data?

Comment: Hard to be sure without seeing actual data, but I think you need to use something like `DimDate[Datekey] <= Today()` in the filter.

Answer (score 1):

Following correction would solve your problem. 
Replace first parameter to Calculate
     From "SUM( FactSales[SalesAmount]"
     with  **"IF( MAX(DimDate[DateKey]) > TODAY(),Blank(),SUM( FactSales[SalesAmount])"**.

```
=CALCULATE( IF( MAX(DimDate[DateKey]) > TODAY(),Blank(),SUM( FactSales[SalesAmount]),
    FILTER(
        ALL( DimDate) ,
        DimDate[DateKey] <= Max( DimDate[DateKey] )
    )
)
```